# What does this paragraph lack?

Tags: grammaticality

I think this sentence is grammatically incorrect, but I am not sure what the author lacks here. Can somebody help me?

Signals from Washington that it was prepared to take further action against the Syrian government **if it thought it was using chemical weapons was the main driver**, with uncertainty about forthcoming elections in France also simmering.

Source: http://www.reuters.com/article/us-global-markets-idUSKBN17B135?il=0

Comment: If "strict mode" is on, subject-verb number agreement.  With your edit, you have bolded an if-clause along with the predicate of the main clause.  **Signals...** is the subject.  The main verb is **was** [sic]. Put a comma after **government** and after **weapons**.

Comment: @TRomano: I don't think so, because if "signals" is the subject, the main verb can't be "was".

Comment: @haile: When TRomano writes [sic] it means "this is what is written, but I don't think it's right". He is indicating that **was** should be **were**. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sic

Comment: The writer/editor should have reviewed this for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, you need to look at the context. Here's what the sentence means, with some text from the preceding paragraph added and the clauses rearranged and annotated for ease of understanding:

> Nervous investors turned to the safety of gold: **signals from Washington were the main driver**. The signals were that [Washington] was prepared to take further action against the Syrian government if [Washington] thought [Syria] was using chemical weapons.

Looking at it the original text, I have highlighted the main clause: we can see that **was** should be **were** in order to agree with **signals**:

> **Signals from Washington** that it was prepared to take further action against the Syrian government if it thought it was using chemical weapons **were the main driver**, with uncertainty about forthcoming elections in France also simmering